# What is the opposite of parody?

Tags: genre, dramatic-writing, comedy

What I mean is a parody/spoof is a comical adaptation.

The opposite would be a dramatic adaptation.

For examples, both *Batman: the Movie* (1966, Leslie H. Martinson, Disney/20th Century Studios) and *The Dark Knight Trilogy* (2005-2012, Christopher Nolan, Warner Bros. Pictures) are *Batman* adaptations, one has everything played for laughs, and the other has everything played for drama.

I would call that a tragedy because it rhymes with parody.

Comment: This doesn't really feel like you're asking something.

Comment: '66 Batman is a parody of the 1943 Batman serial – very close (in spirit) to the entertainingly stupid original. It tapped nostalgia, but it was a *specific thing* the generation knew, like how The Orville is funnier if you know ST:TNG…. Antonym of this would not be 'tragedy' it would be a stale corporate IP that is dusted off every decade for an ever-increasingly 'grittier' fan-service reboot… OVA anime..., anything directed by Michael Bay… It attempts to erase childhood associations through a more aggressive, uglier adult experience. 'Anti-nostalgia'.

Comment: The opposite of parody is a dromedary, of course.

Comment: Détournement comes close https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9tournement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think that a parody need be comical or humorous.

The [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parody) (sense 1) reads:

> a literary or musical work in which the style of an author or work is closely imitated for comic effect or in ridicule // *wrote a hilarious parody of a popular song*

The lead section of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parody) reads:

> A **parody**, also called a **spoof**, a **send-up**, a **take-off**, a **lampoon**, a **play on (something)**, or a **caricature**, is a creative work designed to imitate, comment on, and/or make fun of its subject by means of satiric or ironic imitation. Often its subject is an original work or some aspect of it — theme/content, author, style, etc. But a parody can also be about a real-life person (e.g. a politician), event, or movement (e.g. the French Revolution or 1960s counterculture). Literary scholar Professor Simon Dentith defines parody as "any cultural practice which provides a relatively polemical allusive imitation of another cultural production or practice".[1] The literary theorist Linda Hutcheon said "parody ... is imitation, not always at the expense of the parodied text."

The [Britannica article]([https://www.britannica.com/art/parody-literature\](https://www.britannica.com/art/parody-literature%5C))  reads:

> **parody**, in literature, an imitation of the style and manner of a particular writer or school of writers. Parody is typically negative in intent: it calls attention to a writer’s perceived weaknesses or a school’s overused conventions and seeks to ridicule them. Parody can, however, serve a constructive purpose, or it can be an expression of admiration. It may also simply be a comic exercise. The word parody is derived from the Greek parōidía, “a song sung alongside another.”
>
> ...
>
> ...  Miguel de Cervantes also took the romance as his target in *Don Quixote* (1605, 1615), while François Rabelais parodied the Scholastics in *Gargantua and Pantagruel* (1532–64). William Shakespeare mimicked Christopher Marlowe’s high dramatic style in the players’ scene in *Hamlet* (c. 1599–1601) and was himself parodied by John Marston, who skewered Shakespeare’s poem "Venus and Adonis" with his "The Metamorphosis of Pigmalions Image" (1598).

The page ["Parofy](https://literaryterms.net/parody/) from *Literary Terms*] reads:

> A parody is a work that’s created by imitating an existing original work in order to make fun of or comment on an aspect of the original. Parodies can target celebrities, politicians, authors, a style or trend, or any other interesting subject.

The [definition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/parody) from *The Free Dictionary* reads:

> 1.a A literary or artistic work that uses imitation, as of the characteristic style of an author or a work, for comic effect or ridicule. ...
> 3. *Music* The practice of reworking an already established composition, especially the incorporation into the Mass of material borrowed from other works, such as motets or madrigals.

Thus a parody is often created with comic or humorous intent, but need not be. A work that imitates another in order to make a serious comment or criticism of it, or a serious comment on some related topic is still a parody.

A mention of or quotation from an existing work would be a ***literary allusion***.

I do not see the need to coin a new term, particularly one likely to be confused with an existing widely used term, as the use of "tragedy" as suggested in the question would be.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that parodies are generally targeted at specific works, or at least at coherent bodies of work.  Batman is a large corpus, having many different takes; a parody would pick out one version and parody that.  Merely doing a different take on the Batman mythos is not doing a serious parody of the comic versions.

When a work targets comic or light-hearted works to show them in a more serious light, this is generally called deconstruction.  Taking one of the more light-hearted version and showing, perhaps, that Robin would end up with Post-Traumatic Stress Syndrome as a result of having been, effectively, a child soldier.